# ¿Cómo puedo ver o ejecutar scripts de un documento externo en javascript en otro documento js?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo: Tengo un main.js donde quiero ver un array que está en otro archivo js. Que funciones o métodos me permiten hacer eso en vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

Todo lo que esta lineal en los scripts esta disponible en orden de ejecución separado por expresiones o declaraciones.

Si quieres ver lo de un script en otro simplemente declara primero el script del array y despues el script del codigo que necesita el array.

Otra cosa que te puede afectar es el scope del array, que puede estar en el window, en una funcion, en un catch, etc. Dependiendo de su nivel de acceso es donde lo vas a encontrar o si es accesible.

```
<script>
    var array = [1,2,3];
    function f () {
        var funcArray = [1,2,3];
    }
</script>
<script>
    // accesible, devuelve 1
    console.log(array[0]);
    //no accesible, devuelve undefined
    console.log(typeof funcArray);
    //todavia no existe, devuelve undefined
    console.log(typeof array2);
</script>
<script>
    var array2 = [1,2,3];
</script>
```